# How can I plot residuals in seasonal_decompose(df['Employees'], model='add') as a line chart, not a scatterplot?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

the code is:

```
result = seasonal_decompose(df['Employees'], model='add')
result.plot()
```

The output is
[the following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATw4h.png)

I would like to have my residuals in a line chart. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why the residuals would show up as a scatter plot instead of a line chart as a line chart is the default behavior of the .plot() method - perhaps it has something to do with overlapping datetimes in your data, but we should expect the timegrains of observed + trend + seasonal + residuals to line up exactly. If anyone can answer this I would be curious how this is possible. Was your data obtained from somewhere online so I can reproduce your output exactly?

For now, since `result` is an object of type `DecomposeResult`, you can try accessing its attributes one at a time: `result.observed`, `result.trend`, `result.seasonal`, `result.resid`, and plot them together on the same subplot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 1, sharex=True)
result.observed.plot(ax=axes[0], legend=False)
result.trend.plot(ax=axes[1], legend=False)
result.seasonal.plot(ax=axes[2], legend=False)
result.resid.plot(ax=axes[3], legend=False)

axes[0].set_ylabel('Observed')
axes[1].set_ylabel('Trend')
axes[2].set_ylabel('Seasonal')
axes[3].set_ylabel('Residual')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

add extrapolate_trend='freq', period=3 as parameters to seasonal_decompose